# Calculate Average Dynamically in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, average

I have 3 variables A, B, C. I need to calculate the average of the values of A, B and C.

But sometimes I want to exclude a variable when it has no data.

for example,
if all variable have data, formula should be (A+B+C)/3.
if A didn't have data, formula should be like (B+C)/2.

Any suggestions?

I tried avg() function, but that didn't worked as expected.

Comment: having no data means is A=None?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following, which basically excludes the value from the list if its None

```py
import numpy as np
A=None
B=5
C=4

np.mean([num for num in[A,B,C] if num is not None])
>>> 4.5
```

Comment: That would also exclude zeros, right? Also, why numpy? And do you have a typo with `i` vs `num`?

Comment: @DanGetz thanks a lot for the comment. You are totally correct that was excluding zeros, thanks for the typo. Numpy because I think is fast an avoids writing the formula